# How to use a single connection string in whole winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Winforms, MySQL and C# in my project. In that I use a connection string in the app settings.

At each new page I will declare a connection string as public and use this string in the connection.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
```

I want to declare this MyConString only one time in the whole application. How to do this? Where to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you should expose your connection string to your Forms, they don't need to know that. You can encapsulate the creation of connections with a simple factory.

```
public class ConnectionFactory
{
    public static MySqlConnection Create()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."];
        MySqlConnection conection = new MySqlConnection(Config.ConnectionStr);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Then when you need a connection in a Form you can do:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArg args)
{
    using ( var connection = ConnectionFactory.Create() )
    {
       connection.Execute("...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the following:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string ConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."];
}
```

You can then use it in your code

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Config.ConnectionStr);
```

Comment: The `Config` class example needs to be added in a single place in the project. It probably should be in a file on its own.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested approach is available at an MSDN article titled [Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The following samples are slightly modified from this article.

After storing your connection string in an [app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374182%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) file, you can retrieve all connection strings like so:

```
static void GetConnectionStrings()
{
    var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
    if (settings != null) {
        foreach(ConnectionStringSettings cs in settings) {
            Console.WriteLine(cs.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(cs.ProviderName);
            Console.WriteLine(cs.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

You could alternatively get the connection string by name:

```
// Returns null if the name is not found.
static string GetConnectionStringByName(string name)
{
    string returnValue = null;   // Assume failure.
    var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];
    if (settings != null) {
        returnValue = settings.ConnectionString;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This also gives you the ability of [Securing Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so that your database username & password are not embedded into your application assembly in clear-text.

Answer (score 2):

[Enterpise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) from Microsoft  have great DataAccess part which beside other prtoblem solving and this one

Answer (score 2):

You may have a separate class to handle databases and add the connection string as a field there. Each time you want to connect to the database, you may use that class. Also if you may use a property to access the string outside the class if you require.

Hope this helps...